# How to Convert NSURL to CFURLRef

Tags: operating-system, pdf-generation, nsurl, nssavepanel, nspanel

Apple gives sample code for Creating PDF document. But It uses CFURLRef

NSPanel savepanel gives NSURL.

I can't convert  NSURL to CFURLRef

```
 path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, filename, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

 url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
 NSLog(@"CFURLRef %@",url);
```

output is

2016-04-22 00:34:26.648 XXX Analysis[12242:813106] CFURLRef AnalysisReport.pdf -- file:///Users/xxxxxx/Library/Containers/com.xxxxxx.xxxnalysis/Data/

convert code which i find

```
url = (__bridge CFURLRef)theFile;
NSLog(@"NSURL %@",url);
```

output is

2016-04-22 00:37:20.494 XXX Analysis[12325:816505] NSURL file:///Users/xxxxxx/Documents/xxxnalysis.pdf

at the  end  PDF file is saved but Program crash when the NSPanel closed.

Comment: how does the crash looks like? Any errors in sandboxing log?

Comment: I found my answer.  if you don't create  CFStringRef  with  CFStringCreateWithCString .  You dont need to call  CFRelease(url);

Answer (score 13):

`CFURLRef` and `NSURL` are toll-free bridged.  So typically, you would just do this:

```
NSURL *url = ...;
CFURLRef cfurl = CFBridgingRetain(url);
```

And when you no longer need the CFURL object:

```
CFRelease(cfurl);
```

Or if you're reasonably certain that the NSURL will stick around long enough, you can just do

```
CFURLRef cfurl = (__bridge CFURLRef)url;
```

If you're getting a crash, that probably means you're over-releasing something — specifically, that you're releasing an object that you don't own.  I would suggest reading Apple's docs on object ownership:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html

Comment: How would I do this in Swift? Using CFBridgingRetain causes a runtime error and using (__bridge CFURLRef) causes a coding error.

Comment: Apparently, in Swift, those types are already bridged to native objects, so you should presumably just be able to cast it.  See https://en.swifter.tips/toll-free/

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't work, but I found a simpler way around what I wanted to do. Thank you.